# How to solve "Exception: Missing default handler <on_button_release> in <SmartStartMenu>" error in Python Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

**My question:** Using Kivy for Python, how do I actually solve the error of "`Exception: Missing default handler <on_button_release> in <SmartStartMenu>`"?

I'm following [this guy](https://kivyspacegame.wordpress.com/2014/08/10/tutorial-flappy-ship-part-2-build-simple-menus-and-animate-your-games-using-clock/)'s tutorial and the code is from 2014, a bit old. I've tried and corrected about a dozen things but after a few hours I'm really stuck with an error. I searched for a solution everywhere but nothing similar came up. Probably it's just my lack of knowledge, but hey, I'll try my best to learn from you experienced fellas ^^

So, when I run this:

```
'''---------- Original file: https://kivyspacegame.wordpress.com/2014/06/20/flappy-ship-a-step-by-step-game-tutorial-part-1/  ----------'''


# Importations
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color, Canvas
from functools import partial
from random import *

# setup graphics
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', 0)

# Graphics fix
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.clearcolor = (0, 0, 0, 1.)


# Window.clearcolor = (1,0,0,1.)
class MyButton(Button):
    # class used to get uniform button styles
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.font_size = Window.width * 0.018


class SmartMenu(Widget):
    # the instance created by this class will appear
    # when the game is started for the first time
    buttonList = []

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # create custom events first
        self.register_event_type('on_button_release')
        # creating a custom event called 'on_button_release' that will
        # be used to pass information from the menu to the parent instance

        super(SmartMenu, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.layout.width = Window.width / 2
        self.layout.height = Window.height / 2
        self.layout.x = Window.width / 2 - self.layout.width / 2
        self.layout.y = Window.height / 2 - self.layout.height / 2
        self.add_widget(self.layout)


def on_button_release(self, *args):
    print('The on_button_release event was just dispatched', args)
    # don't need to do anything here. needed for dispatch
    pass


def callback(self, instance):
    print('The button %s is being pressed' % instance.text)
    self.buttonText = instance.text
    self.dispatch('on_button_release')
    # dispatching the callback event 'on_button_release' to
    # tell teh parent instance to read the button text


def addButtons(self):
    for k in self.buttonList:
        tmpBtn = MyButton(text=k)
        tmpBtn.background_color = [.4, .4, .4, .4]
        tmpBtn.bind(on_release=self.callback)  # when the button is released the callback function is called
        self.layout.add_widget(tmpBtn)


def buildUp(self):
    # self.colorWindow()
    self.addButtons()


class SmartStartMenu(SmartMenu):
    # setup the menu button names
    buttonList = ['start', 'about']
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SmartStartMenu, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.layout.width = Window.width / 2
        self.layout.height = Window.height / 2
        self.layout.x = Window.width / 2 - self.layout.width / 2
        self.layout.y = Window.height / 2 - self.layout.height / 2
        self.add_widget(self.layout)
        self.msg = Label(text='Flappy Ship')
        self.msg.font_size = Window.width * 0.07
        self.msg.pos = (Window.width * 0.45, Window.height * 0.75)
        self.add_widget(self.msg)
        self.img = Image(source='lens2.png')
        self.img.size = (Window.width * 1.5, Window.height * 1.5)
        self.img.pos = (-Window.width * 0.2, -Window.height * 0.2)
        self.img.opacity = 0.35
        self.add_widget(self.img)


class WidgetDrawer(Widget):
    # This widget is used to draw all of the objects on the screen
    # it handles the following:
    # widget movement, size, positioning
    def __init__(self, imageStr, **kwargs):
        super(WidgetDrawer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        with self.canvas:
            self.size = (Window.width * .002 * 25, Window.width * .002 * 25)
            self.rect_bg = Rectangle(source=imageStr, pos=self.pos, size=self.size)

            self.bind(pos=self.update_graphics_pos)
            self.x = self.center_x
            self.y = self.center_y
            self.pos = (self.x, self.y)
            self.rect_bg.pos = self.pos

    def update_graphics_pos(self, instance, value):
        self.rect_bg.pos = value

    def setSize(self, width, height):
        self.size = (width, height)

    def setPos(xpos, ypos):
        self.x = xpos
        self.y = ypos


class ScoreWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScoreWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.asteroidScore = 0
        self.currentScore = 0
        with self.canvas:
            tmpPos = (Window.width * 0.25, Window.height * 0.25)
            tmpSize = (Window.width * 0.5, Window.height * 0.5)
            Color(0.1, .1, .1)
            self.scoreRect = Rectangle(pos=tmpPos, size=tmpSize)

    def prepare(self):
        # calculate the score
        try:
            self.finalScore = self.asteroidScore * 100
        except:
            print('problems getting score')
        self.animateScore()

    def animateScore(self):
        # display score at 0 and every time interval add 100 until
        # we reach the final score
        # draw a score widget and schedule updates
        scoreText = 'Score: 0'  # + str(self.finalScore)
        self.scoreLabel = Label(text=scoreText, font_size='20sp')
        self.scoreLabel.x = Window.width * 0.3
        self.scoreLabel.y = Window.height * 0.3
        self.add_widget(self.scoreLabel)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.updateScore, .1)
        self.drawStars()

    def updateScore(self, dt):
        self.currentScore = self.currentScore + 100
        self.scoreLabel.text = 'Score: ' + str(self.currentScore)
        if self.currentScore < self.finalScore:
            Clock.schedule_once(self.updateScore, 0.1)

    def drawStars(self):
        # 0-10 asteroids 0 stars
        # 11-50 asteroids 1 star
        # 51-200 asteroids 2 stars
        # 201-500 asteroids 3 stars
        # 501-1000 asteroids 4 stars
        # 1001+ asteroids 5 stars
        starNumber = 0
        if self.asteroidScore > 10:
            starNumber = 1
        if self.asteroidScore > 50:
            starNumber = 2
        if self.asteroidScore > 200:
            starNumber = 3
        if self.asteroidScore > 500:
            starNumber = 4
        if self.asteroidScore > 1000:
            starNumber = 5

        with self.canvas:
            # draw stars
            # rect one
            starPos = Window.width * 0.27, Window.height * 0.42
            starSize = Window.width * 0.06, Window.width * 0.06
            starString = 'gold_star.png'
        if starNumber < 1:
            starString = 'gray_star.png'
        starRectOne = Rectangle(source=starString, pos=starPos, size=starSize)
        # rect two
        starPos = Window.width * 0.37, Window.height * 0.42
        if starNumber < 2:
            starString = 'gray_star.png'
        starRectTwo = Rectangle(source=starString, pos=starPos, size=starSize)
        # rect three
        starPos = Window.width * 0.47, Window.height * 0.42
        if starNumber < 3:
            starString = 'gray_star.png'
        starRectThree = Rectangle(source=starString, pos=starPos, size=starSize)
        # rect four
        starPos = Window.width * 0.57, Window.height * 0.42
        if starNumber < 4:
            starString = 'gray_star.png'
        starRectFour = Rectangle(source=starString, pos=starPos, size=starSize)
        # rect five
        starPos = Window.width * 0.67, Window.height * 0.42
        if starNumber < 5:
            starString = 'gray_star.png'
            starRectFive = Rectangle(source=starString, pos=starPos, size=starSize)


class Asteroid(WidgetDrawer):
    # Asteroid class. The flappy ship will dodge these
    imageStr = './sandstone_1.png'
    rect_bg = Rectangle(source=imageStr)
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)


def move(self):
    self.x = self.x + self.velocity_x
    self.y = self.y + self.velocity_y


def update(self):
    self.move()


class Ship(WidgetDrawer):
    # Ship class. This is for the main ship object.
    # velocity of ship on x/y axis
    # setup constants, health, etc
    # choose default image:

    impulse = 3
    grav = -0.1

    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    flameSize = (Window.width * .03, Window.width * .03)

    def move(self):
        self.x = self.x + self.velocity_x
        self.y = self.y + self.velocity_y

        # don't let the ship go too far
        if self.y <  Window.height * 0.05:
            # give upwards impulse
            self.impulse = 1
            self.grav = -0.1

        if self.y > Window.height * 0.95:
            self.impulse = -3

    def checkBulletNPCCollision(self, j):
        if self.k.collide_widget(j):
            j.health = j.health - self.k.bulletDamage
            j.attackFlag = 'True'
            # age the bullet
            self.k.age = self.k.lifespan + 10

    def checkBulletStageCollision(self, q):
        if self.k.collide_widget(q):
            # if object type is asteorid
            try:
                if q.type == 'asteroid':
                    q.health = q.health - self.k.bulletDamage
                    self.k.age = self.k.lifespan + 10
            except:
                print('couldnt hit asteroid')


def determineVelocity(self):
    # move the ship up and down
    # we need to take into account our acceleration
    # also want to look at gravity
    self.grav = self.grav * 1.05  # increase gravity
    # set a grav limit
    if self.grav < -4:
        self.grav = -4
    # the ship has a propety called self.impulse which is updated
    # whenever the player touches, pushing the ship up
    # use this impulse to determine the ship velocity
    # also decrease the magnitude of the impulse each time its used

    self.velocity_y = self.impulse + self.grav
    self.impulse = 0.95 * self.impulse


def drawArrow(self, *largs):
    # draw the arrows directly onto the canvas
    with self.canvas:
        flamePos = (self.pos[0] - Window.width * .02, self.pos[1] + Window.width * .01)

        flameRect = Rectangle(source='./flame.png', pos=flamePos, size=self.flameSize)

        # schedule removal

        def removeArrows(arrow, *largs):
            self.canvas.remove(arrow)

        Clock.schedule_once(partial(removeArrows, flameRect), .5)
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.updateArrows, flameRect), 0.1)


def updateArrows(self, arrow, dt):
    with self.canvas:
        arrow.pos = (arrow.pos[0] - 10, arrow.pos[1])

        Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.updateArrows, arrow), 0.1)
    return

def explode(self):
    # create explosion 1
    tmpSize = Window.width * 0.25, Window.width * 0.2
    tmpPos = (self.x - Window.width * 0.095, self.y - Window.width * 0.08)
    with self.canvas:  # create an explosion image,
        self.explosionRect = Rectangle(source='./explosion1.png', pos=tmpPos, size=tmpSize)

    def changeExplosion(rect, newSource, *largs):
        rect.source = newSource

    # schedule explosion two
    Clock.schedule_once(partial(changeExplosion, self.explosionRect, './explosion2.png'), 0.2)
    # schedule explosion three
    Clock.schedule_once(partial(changeExplosion, self.explosionRect, './explosion3.png'), 0.4)
    # schedule explosoin four
    Clock.schedule_once(partial(changeExplosion, self.explosionRect, './explosion4.png'), 0.6)
    Clock.schedule_once(partial(changeExplosion, self.explosionRect, './explosion5.png'), 0.8)

    def removeExplosion(rect, *largs):
        self.canvas.remove(rect)  # remove the explosion drawing

    Clock.schedule_once(partial(removeExplosion, self.explosionRect), 1)


def update(self):
    self.determineVelocity()
    self.move()


class GUI(Widget):
    # this is the main widget that contains the game. This is the primary object
    # that runs
    asteroidList = []
    # important to use numericproperty here so we can bind a callback
    # to use every time the number changes
    asteroidScore = NumericProperty(0)
    minProb = 1780

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GUI, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # setup label for the score
        self.score = Label(text='0')
        self.score.y = Window.height * 0.8
        self.score.x = Window.width * 0.2

        def check_score(self, obj):
            # update credits
            self.score.text = str(self.asteroidScore)

        self.bind(asteroidScore=check_score)
        self.add_widget(self.score)

        # now we create a ship object
        self.ship = Ship(imageStr='./ship.png')
        self.ship.x = Window.width / 4
        self.ship.y = Window.height / 2
        self.add_widget(self.ship)
        # self.ship.drawArrow()#start the flames
        Clock.schedule_interval((self.ship.drawArrow), 0.1)

    def addAsteroid(self):
        # add an asteroid to the screen
        # self.asteroid
        imageNumber = randint(1, 4)
        imageStr = './sandstone_' + str(imageNumber) + '.png'
        tmpAsteroid = Asteroid(imageStr)
        tmpAsteroid.x = Window.width * 0.99

        # randomize y position
        ypos = randint(1, 16)
        ypos = ypos * Window.height * .0625
        tmpAsteroid.y = ypos
        tmpAsteroid.velocity_y = 0
        vel = 55  # randint(10,25)
        tmpAsteroid.velocity_x = -0.1 * vel
        self.asteroidList.append(tmpAsteroid)
        self.add_widget(tmpAsteroid)

    def drawTouchResponse(self, x, y):
        # draw the arrows directly onto the canvas
        with self.canvas:
            tmpSize = Window.width * 0.07, Window.width * 0.07
            tmpPos = (x - self.width / 4, y - self.height / 4)
            self.arrowRect = Rectangle(source='./flame1.png', pos=tmpPos, size=tmpSize)

        # schedule removal
        def removeArrows(arrow, *largs):
            self.canvas.remove(arrow)

        def changeExplosion(rect, newSource, *largs):
            rect.source = newSource

        # schedule explosion two
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(changeExplosion, self.arrowRect, './flame2.png'), 0.15)
        # schedule explosion three
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(changeExplosion, self.arrowRect, './flame3.png'), 0.3)
        # schedule explosoin four
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(changeExplosion, self.arrowRect, './flame4.png'), 0.45)
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(removeArrows, self.arrowRect), 0.6)

    # handle input events
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.ship.impulse = 3
        self.ship.grav = -0.1
        self.drawTouchResponse(touch.x, touch.y)

    def showScore(self):
        # this function will draw the score keeping widget, tabulate the score
        # and rank with stars
        self.scoreWidget = ScoreWidget()
        self.scoreWidget.asteroidScore = self.asteroidScore  # pass on score
        self.scoreWidget.prepare()
        self.add_widget(self.scoreWidget)

    def removeScore(self):
        self.remove_widget(self.scoreWidget)

    def gameOver(self):
        # add a restart button
        restartButton = MyButton(text='Try Again')

        # restartButton.background_color = (.5,.5,1,.2)
        def restart_button(obj):
            # reset game
            self.removeScore()

            for k in self.asteroidList:
                self.remove_widget(k)
                self.ship.xpos = Window.width * 0.25
                self.ship.ypos = Window.height * 0.5
                self.minProb = 1780
                self.asteroidScore = 0
                self.asteroidList = []

            self.parent.remove_widget(restartButton)
            Clock.unschedule(self.update)
            Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
            restartButton.size = (Window.width * .3, Window.width * .1)
            restartButton.pos = Window.width * 0.5 - restartButton.width / 2, Window.height * 0.53
            restartButton.bind(on_release=restart_button)
            # we will want to bind the parent to listen for things from certain bubbles

            # *** It's important that the parent get the button so you can click on it
            # otherwise you can't click through the main game's canvas
            self.parent.add_widget(restartButton)

            # now draw the score widget
            self.showScore()

    def update(self, dt):
        # This update function is the main update function for the game
        # All of the game logic has its origin here
        # events are setup here as well

        # update game objects
        # update ship
        self.ship.update()
        # update asteroids
        # randomly add an asteroid
        tmpCount = randint(1, 1800)
        if tmpCount > self.minProb:
            self.addAsteroid()
            if self.minProb < 1300:
                self.minProb = 1300
            self.minProb = self.minProb - 1

        for k in self.asteroidList:
            # check for collision with ship
            if k.collide_widget(self.ship):
                # game over routine
                self.gameOver()
                Clock.unschedule(self.update)
                # add reset button
                self.ship.explode()
                k.update()

        # check to see if asteroid is off of screen
        if k.x < -100:
            # since it's off the screen, remove the asteroid
            self.remove_widget(k)
            self.asteroidScore = self.asteroidScore + 1
            # remove asteroids off screen

        tmpAsteroidList = self.asteroidList
        tmpAsteroidList[:] = [x for x in tmpAsteroidList if (x.x > - 100)]
        self.asteroidList = tmpAsteroidList


class ClientApp(App):

    def build(self):
        # this is where the root widget goes
        # should be a canvas
        self.parent = Widget()  #

        self.app = GUI()
        # Start the game clock (runs update function once every (1/60) seconds
        # Clock.schedule_interval(app.update, 1.0/60.0)
        # add the start menu

    self.sm = SmartStartMenu()
    self.sm.buildUp()

    def check_button(obj):
        # check to see which button was pressed
        if self.sm.buttonText == 'start':
            # remove menu
            self.parent.remove_widget(self.sm)
            # start the game
            print('we should start the game now')
            Clock.unschedule(self.app.update)
            Clock.schedule_interval(self.app.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
            try:
                self.parent.remove_widget(self.aboutText)
            except:
                pass
        if self.sm.buttonText == 'about':
            self.aboutText = Label(
                text='Flappy Ship is made by Molecular Flow Games \n Check out: https://kivyspacegame.wordpress.com')
            self.aboutText.pos = (Window.width * 0.45, Window.height * 0.35)
            self.parent.add_widget(self.aboutText)
        # bind a callback function that repsonds to event 'on_button_release' by calling function check_button
        self.sm.bind(on_button_release=check_button)
        # setup listeners for smartstartmenu
        self.parent.add_widget(self.sm)
        self.parent.add_widget(self.app)  # use this hierarchy to make it easy to deal w/buttons
        return self.parent


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ClientApp().run()
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
C:\Users\username>"C:\Users\username\Desktop\Python\tutorials\kivy\Test 3\spacegametest2.py"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\username\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-01-15_27.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.1.17
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.1.9
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.1.12
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.1.22
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6.0 NVIDIA 441.66'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'NVIDIA Corporation'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'GeForce 940MX/PCIe/SSE2'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60 NVIDIA'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Python\tutorials\kivy\Test 3\spacegametest2.py", line 516, in <module>
     class ClientApp(App):
   File "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Python\tutorials\kivy\Test 3\spacegametest2.py", line 528, in ClientApp
     self.sm = SmartStartMenu()
   File "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Python\tutorials\kivy\Test 3\spacegametest2.py", line 93, in __init__
     super(SmartStartMenu, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Python\tutorials\kivy\Test 3\spacegametest2.py", line 49, in __init__
     self.register_event_type('on_button_release')
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 295, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.register_event_type
 Exception: Missing default handler <on_button_release> in <SmartStartMenu>
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there anything you can recommend I should do?

I'll eagerly be looking forward to any comment or suggestion to solve this out!

Thanks in advance and happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various wrong things in the code, but the error you get is because the indentation of the `SmartMenu` and `Ship` class is wrong.
Full fixed code:

```py
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color, Canvas
from functools import partial
from random import *

# setup graphics
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', 0)

# Graphics fix
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.clearcolor = (0, 0, 0, 1.)


# Window.clearcolor = (1,0,0,1.)
class MyButton(Button):
    # class used to get uniform button styles
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.font_size = Window.width * 0.018


class SmartMenu(Widget):
    # the instance created by this class will appear
    # when the game is started for the first time
    buttonList = []

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # create custom events first
        self.register_event_type('on_button_release')
        # creating a custom event called 'on_button_release' that will
        # be used to pass information from the menu to the parent instance

        super(SmartMenu, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.layout.width = Window.width / 2
        self.layout.height = Window.height / 2
        self.layout.x = Window.width / 2 - self.layout.width / 2
        self.layout.y = Window.height / 2 - self.layout.height / 2
        self.add_widget(self.layout)


    def on_button_release(self, *args):
        print('The on_button_release event was just dispatched', args)
        # don't need to do anything here. needed for dispatch
        pass


    def callback(self, instance):
        print('The button %s is being pressed' % instance.text)
        self.buttonText = instance.text
        self.dispatch('on_button_release')
        # dispatching the callback event 'on_button_release' to
        # tell teh parent instance to read the button text


    def addButtons(self):
        for k in self.buttonList:
            tmpBtn = MyButton(text=k)
            tmpBtn.background_color = [.4, .4, .4, .4]
            tmpBtn.bind(on_release=self.callback)  # when the button is released the callback function is called
            self.layout.add_widget(tmpBtn)


    def buildUp(self):
        # self.colorWindow()
        self.addButtons()


class SmartStartMenu(SmartMenu):
    # setup the menu button names
    buttonList = ['start', 'about']
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SmartStartMenu, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.layout.width = Window.width / 2
        self.layout.height = Window.height / 2
        self.layout.x = Window.width / 2 - self.layout.width / 2
        self.layout.y = Window.height / 2 - self.layout.height / 2
        self.add_widget(self.layout)
        self.msg = Label(text='Flappy Ship')
        self.msg.font_size = Window.width * 0.07
        self.msg.pos = (Window.width * 0.45, Window.height * 0.75)
        self.add_widget(self.msg)
        self.img = Image(source='images/lens2.png')
        self.img.size = (Window.width * 1.5, Window.height * 1.5)
        self.img.pos = (-Window.width * 0.2, -Window.height * 0.2)
        self.img.opacity = 0.35
        self.add_widget(self.img)


class WidgetDrawer(Widget):
    # This widget is used to draw all of the objects on the screen
    # it handles the following:
    # widget movement, size, positioning
    def __init__(self, imageStr, **kwargs):
        super(WidgetDrawer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        with self.canvas:
            self.size = (Window.width * .002 * 25, Window.width * .002 * 25)
            self.rect_bg = Rectangle(source=imageStr, pos=self.pos, size=self.size)

            self.bind(pos=self.update_graphics_pos)
            self.x = self.center_x
            self.y = self.center_y
            self.pos = (self.x, self.y)
            self.rect_bg.pos = self.pos

    def update_graphics_pos(self, instance, value):
        self.rect_bg.pos = value

    def setSize(self, width, height):
        self.size = (width, height)

    def setPos(xpos, ypos):
        self.x = xpos
        self.y = ypos


class ScoreWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScoreWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.asteroidScore = 0
        self.currentScore = 0
        with self.canvas:
            tmpPos = (Window.width * 0.25, Window.height * 0.25)
            tmpSize = (Window.width * 0.5, Window.height * 0.5)
            Color(0.1, .1, .1)
            self.scoreRect = Rectangle(pos=tmpPos, size=tmpSize)

    def prepare(self):
        # calculate the score
        try:
            self.finalScore = self.asteroidScore * 100
        except:
            print('problems getting score')
        self.animateScore()

    def animateScore(self):
        # display score at 0 and every time interval add 100 until
        # we reach the final score
        # draw a score widget and schedule updates
        scoreText = 'Score: 0'  # + str(self.finalScore)
        self.scoreLabel = Label(text=scoreText, font_size='20sp')
        self.scoreLabel.x = Window.width * 0.3
        self.scoreLabel.y = Window.height * 0.3
        self.add_widget(self.scoreLabel)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.updateScore, .1)
        self.drawStars()

    def updateScore(self, dt):
        self.currentScore = self.currentScore + 100
        self.scoreLabel.text = 'Score: ' + str(self.currentScore)
        if self.currentScore < self.finalScore:
            Clock.schedule_once(self.updateScore, 0.1)

    def drawStars(self):
        # 0-10 asteroids 0 stars
        # 11-50 asteroids 1 star
        # 51-200 asteroids 2 stars
        # 201-500 asteroids 3 stars
        # 501-1000 asteroids 4 stars
        # 1001+ asteroids 5 stars
        starNumber = 0
        if self.asteroidScore > 10:
            starNumber = 1
        if self.asteroidScore > 50:
            starNumber = 2
        if self.asteroidScore > 200:
            starNumber = 3
        if self.asteroidScore > 500:
            starNumber = 4
        if self.asteroidScore > 1000:
            starNumber = 5

        with self.canvas:
            # draw stars
            # rect one
            starPos = Window.width * 0.27, Window.height * 0.42
            starSize = Window.width * 0.06, Window.width * 0.06
            starString = 'images/gold_star.png'
        if starNumber < 1:
            starString = 'images/gray_star.png'
        starRectOne = Rectangle(source=starString, pos=starPos, size=starSize)
        # rect two
        starPos = Window.width * 0.37, Window.height * 0.42
        if starNumber < 2:
            starString = 'images/gray_star.png'
        starRectTwo = Rectangle(source=starString, pos=starPos, size=starSize)
        # rect three
        starPos = Window.width * 0.47, Window.height * 0.42
        if starNumber < 3:
            starString = 'images/gray_star.png'
        starRectThree = Rectangle(source=starString, pos=starPos, size=starSize)
        # rect four
        starPos = Window.width * 0.57, Window.height * 0.42
        if starNumber < 4:
            starString = 'images/gray_star.png'
        starRectFour = Rectangle(source=starString, pos=starPos, size=starSize)
        # rect five
        starPos = Window.width * 0.67, Window.height * 0.42
        if starNumber < 5:
            starString = 'images/gray_star.png'
            starRectFive = Rectangle(source=starString, pos=starPos, size=starSize)


class Asteroid(WidgetDrawer):
    # Asteroid class. The flappy ship will dodge these
    imageStr = 'images/sandstone_1.png'
    rect_bg = Rectangle(source=imageStr)
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)


    def move(self):
        self.x = self.x + self.velocity_x
        self.y = self.y + self.velocity_y


    def update(self):
        self.move()


class Ship(WidgetDrawer):
    # Ship class. This is for the main ship object.
    # velocity of ship on x/y axis
    # setup constants, health, etc
    # choose default image:

    impulse = 3
    grav = -0.1

    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    flameSize = (Window.width * .03, Window.width * .03)

    def move(self):
        self.x = self.x + self.velocity_x
        self.y = self.y + self.velocity_y

        # don't let the ship go too far
        if self.y <  Window.height * 0.05:
            # give upwards impulse
            self.impulse = 1
            self.grav = -0.1

        if self.y > Window.height * 0.95:
            self.impulse = -3

    def checkBulletNPCCollision(self, j):
        if self.k.collide_widget(j):
            j.health = j.health - self.k.bulletDamage
            j.attackFlag = 'True'
            # age the bullet
            self.k.age = self.k.lifespan + 10

    def checkBulletStageCollision(self, q):
        if self.k.collide_widget(q):
            # if object type is asteorid
            try:
                if q.type == 'asteroid':
                    q.health = q.health - self.k.bulletDamage
                    self.k.age = self.k.lifespan + 10
            except:
                print('couldnt hit asteroid')


    def determineVelocity(self):
        # move the ship up and down
        # we need to take into account our acceleration
        # also want to look at gravity
        self.grav = self.grav * 1.05  # increase gravity
        # set a grav limit
        if self.grav < -4:
            self.grav = -4
        # the ship has a propety called self.impulse which is updated
        # whenever the player touches, pushing the ship up
        # use this impulse to determine the ship velocity
        # also decrease the magnitude of the impulse each time its used

        self.velocity_y = self.impulse + self.grav
        self.impulse = 0.95 * self.impulse


    def drawArrow(self, *largs):
        # draw the arrows directly onto the canvas
        with self.canvas:
            flamePos = (self.pos[0] - Window.width * .02, self.pos[1] + Window.width * .01)

            flameRect = Rectangle(source='images/flame.png',
                                  pos=flamePos, size=self.flameSize)

            # schedule removal

            def removeArrows(arrow, *largs):
                self.canvas.remove(arrow)

            Clock.schedule_once(partial(removeArrows, flameRect), .5)
            Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.updateArrows, flameRect), 0.1)


    def updateArrows(self, arrow, dt):
        with self.canvas:
            arrow.pos = (arrow.pos[0] - 10, arrow.pos[1])

            Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.updateArrows, arrow), 0.1)
        return

    def explode(self):
        # create explosion 1
        tmpSize = Window.width * 0.25, Window.width * 0.2
        tmpPos = (self.x - Window.width * 0.095, self.y - Window.width * 0.08)
        with self.canvas:  # create an explosion image,
            self.explosionRect = Rectangle(source='images/explosion1.png', pos=tmpPos, size=tmpSize)

        def changeExplosion(rect, newSource, *largs):
            rect.source = newSource

        # schedule explosion two
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(changeExplosion, self.explosionRect,
                                    'images/explosion2.png'), 0.2)
        # schedule explosion three
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(changeExplosion, self.explosionRect,
                                    'images/explosion3.png'), 0.4)
        # schedule explosoin four
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(changeExplosion, self.explosionRect,
                                    'images/explosion4.png'), 0.6)
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(changeExplosion, self.explosionRect,
                                    'images/explosion5.png'), 0.8)

        def removeExplosion(rect, *largs):
            self.canvas.remove(rect)  # remove the explosion drawing

        Clock.schedule_once(partial(removeExplosion, self.explosionRect), 1)


    def update(self):
        self.determineVelocity()
        self.move()


class GUI(Widget):
    # this is the main widget that contains the game. This is the primary object
    # that runs
    asteroidList = []
    # important to use numericproperty here so we can bind a callback
    # to use every time the number changes
    asteroidScore = NumericProperty(0)
    minProb = 1780

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GUI, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # setup label for the score
        self.score = Label(text='0')
        self.score.y = Window.height * 0.8
        self.score.x = Window.width * 0.2

        def check_score(self, obj):
            # update credits
            self.score.text = str(self.asteroidScore)

        self.bind(asteroidScore=check_score)
        self.add_widget(self.score)

        # now we create a ship object
        self.ship = Ship(imageStr='./ship.png')
        self.ship.x = Window.width / 4
        self.ship.y = Window.height / 2
        self.add_widget(self.ship)
        # self.ship.drawArrow()#start the flames
        Clock.schedule_interval((self.ship.drawArrow), 0.1)

    def addAsteroid(self):
        # add an asteroid to the screen
        # self.asteroid
        imageNumber = randint(1, 4)
        imageStr = 'images/sandstone_' + str(imageNumber) + '.png'
        tmpAsteroid = Asteroid(imageStr)
        tmpAsteroid.x = Window.width * 0.99

        # randomize y position
        ypos = randint(1, 16)
        ypos = ypos * Window.height * .0625
        tmpAsteroid.y = ypos
        tmpAsteroid.velocity_y = 0
        vel = 55  # randint(10,25)
        tmpAsteroid.velocity_x = -0.1 * vel
        self.asteroidList.append(tmpAsteroid)
        self.add_widget(tmpAsteroid)

    def drawTouchResponse(self, x, y):
        # draw the arrows directly onto the canvas
        with self.canvas:
            tmpSize = Window.width * 0.07, Window.width * 0.07
            tmpPos = (x - self.width / 4, y - self.height / 4)
            self.arrowRect = Rectangle(source='images/flame1.png',
                                       pos=tmpPos, size=tmpSize)

        # schedule removal
        def removeArrows(arrow, *largs):
            self.canvas.remove(arrow)

        def changeExplosion(rect, newSource, *largs):
            rect.source = newSource

        # schedule explosion two
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(changeExplosion, self.arrowRect,
                                    'images/flame2.png'), 0.15)
        # schedule explosion three
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(changeExplosion, self.arrowRect,
                                    'images/flame3.png'), 0.3)
        # schedule explosoin four
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(changeExplosion, self.arrowRect,
                                    'images/flame4.png'), 0.45)
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(removeArrows, self.arrowRect), 0.6)

    # handle input events
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.ship.impulse = 3
        self.ship.grav = -0.1
        self.drawTouchResponse(touch.x, touch.y)

    def showScore(self):
        # this function will draw the score keeping widget, tabulate the score
        # and rank with stars
        self.scoreWidget = ScoreWidget()
        self.scoreWidget.asteroidScore = self.asteroidScore  # pass on score
        self.scoreWidget.prepare()
        self.add_widget(self.scoreWidget)

    def removeScore(self):
        self.remove_widget(self.scoreWidget)

    def gameOver(self):
        # add a restart button
        restartButton = MyButton(text='Try Again')

        # restartButton.background_color = (.5,.5,1,.2)
        def restart_button(obj):
            # reset game
            self.removeScore()

            for k in self.asteroidList:
                self.remove_widget(k)
                self.ship.xpos = Window.width * 0.25
                self.ship.ypos = Window.height * 0.5
                self.minProb = 1780
                self.asteroidScore = 0
                self.asteroidList = []

            self.parent.remove_widget(restartButton)
            Clock.unschedule(self.update)
            Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
            restartButton.size = (Window.width * .3, Window.width * .1)
            restartButton.pos = Window.width * 0.5 - restartButton.width / 2, Window.height * 0.53
            restartButton.bind(on_release=restart_button)
            # we will want to bind the parent to listen for things from certain bubbles

            # *** It's important that the parent get the button so you can click on it
            # otherwise you can't click through the main game's canvas
            self.parent.add_widget(restartButton)

            # now draw the score widget
            self.showScore()

    def update(self, dt):
        # This update function is the main update function for the game
        # All of the game logic has its origin here
        # events are setup here as well

        # update game objects
        # update ship
        self.ship.update()
        # update asteroids
        # randomly add an asteroid
        tmpCount = randint(1, 1800)
        if tmpCount > self.minProb:
            self.addAsteroid()
            if self.minProb < 1300:
                self.minProb = 1300
            self.minProb = self.minProb - 1

        for k in self.asteroidList:
            # check for collision with ship
            if k.collide_widget(self.ship):
                # game over routine
                self.gameOver()
                Clock.unschedule(self.update)
                # add reset button
                self.ship.explode()
                k.update()

            # check to see if asteroid is off of screen
            if k.x < -100:
                # since it's off the screen, remove the asteroid
                self.remove_widget(k)
                self.asteroidScore = self.asteroidScore + 1
                # remove asteroids off screen

        tmpAsteroidList = self.asteroidList
        tmpAsteroidList[:] = [x for x in tmpAsteroidList if (x.x > - 100)]
        self.asteroidList = tmpAsteroidList


class ClientApp(App):

    def build(self):
        # this is where the root widget goes
        # should be a canvas
        self.parent = Widget()  #

        self.app = GUI()
        # Start the game clock (runs update function once every (1/60) seconds
        # Clock.schedule_interval(app.update, 1.0/60.0)
        # add the start menu

        self.sm = SmartStartMenu()
        self.sm.buildUp()

        def check_button(obj):
            # check to see which button was pressed
            if self.sm.buttonText == 'start':
                # remove menu
                self.parent.remove_widget(self.sm)
                # start the game
                print('we should start the game now')
                Clock.unschedule(self.app.update)
                Clock.schedule_interval(self.app.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
                try:
                    self.parent.remove_widget(self.aboutText)
                except:
                    pass
            if self.sm.buttonText == 'about':
                self.aboutText = Label(
                    text='Flappy Ship is made by Molecular Flow Games \n Check out: https://kivyspacegame.wordpress.com')
                self.aboutText.pos = (Window.width * 0.45, Window.height * 0.35)
                self.parent.add_widget(self.aboutText)
        # bind a callback function that repsonds to event 'on_button_release' by calling function check_button
        self.sm.bind(on_button_release=check_button)
        # setup listeners for smartstartmenu
        self.parent.add_widget(self.sm)
        self.parent.add_widget(self.app)  # use this hierarchy to make it easy to deal w/buttons
        return self.parent


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ClientApp().run()
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much @noEmbryo! Running the code you fixed seems to cause no errors at all. I'm getting just an empty black screen, though, which must be because of all the other wrong things like you mentioned. I'll be looking into it and try to make this work. Thank you again! Feel free to provide further clarification when you feel like doing so.

Comment: @ThisNicknameIsAlreadyInUse Do you provide all the images that the code needs?

Comment: @ThisNicknameIsAlreadyInUse Updated my answer.. It should work now (if you add the images in an `images` folder.. ;o)

Comment: I cannot thank you enough! I've been trying for days now to get this code work. It still does need a few fixes but it will be easier thanks to your updated code.